# A question about Galois characters

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-representations

Let $F$ be a number field and $\chi:\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/F)\to\overline{\mathbb{Q}_\ell}^{\times}$ ($\ell$ a prime) a Galois character. My question is: Can we find a finite extension $K/F$ such that $\chi_{|\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/K)}=1$

Comment: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2961446/why-can-we-always-restrict-an-galois-representation-so-that-it-becomes-unramifie) might be what you're looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Galois theory, your question is equivalent to asking whether all $\ell$-adic Galois characters have finite image. Unlike with complex-valued characters, there are plenty of infinite image $\ell$-adic Galois characters.

The most important example is the $\ell$-adic cyclotomic character. Take $F=\mathbb Q$ and define $\chi$ as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q) &\to \mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\zeta_{\ell^\infty})\ /\ \mathbb Q)\\
&= \varprojlim_{n}\ \mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\zeta_{\ell^n})/\mathbb Q)\\
&=\varprojlim_{n}\ (\mathbb Z/\ell^n\mathbb Z)^\times\\
&= \mathbb Z_\ell^\times\subset \mathbb Q_\ell^\times.
\end{align}
$$

Here $\zeta_{\ell^n}$ is a primitive $\ell^n$-th root of unity, and $\mathbb Q(\zeta_{\ell^\infty})$ is the field obtained by adjoining all $\ell$-power roots of unity. This map is surjective (onto $\mathbb Z_\ell^\times)$, so has infinite image. It only becomes trivial after restriction to $\mathbb Q(\zeta_{\ell^\infty})$, which is an infinite extension.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.